# How do I make Except print out my error messages?

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch, except

my name is Ana, and I'm a student taking a course in Python. I'm still a beginner and I'm recently learning how to use the `try` and `except` function. However, I'm trying to make the program print an error message when input is a string and not an integer. Instead, it prints out its own error message instead of mine. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to ask my teacher because I don't want to keep asking him to check my code. Here is a screenshot of my attempt.

[image: (Try/Except Attempt)]
Thanks for your help.

Sincerely

Ana Baird

Comment: formatting improvment

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can throw an exception needs to be placed inside the `try:` block. In your code example, place the `integer = int(userin)` inside it, otherwise if a user enters a string Python will throw its own error.

And in the future, please don't post a picture of your code. Instead use the formatting provided on the site or a pastebin link  :)